# There was an error parsing JSON data Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, http, http-headers

Everyone.
I built a backend api with php to create a user and get user data. In "GET" method, there is no error for getting user data but in "PUT" method, I am getting such error. I built this api to integrate with Angular4 web app. So, I tested this api with the web app. Then, I am getting the following errors:

> OPTIONS http://localhost/api/users 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Failed to load http://localhost/api/users: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
>
> ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false,
>   statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}

Here is the .htaccess file to change the api url.(eg. http://localhost/api/users/1)

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^users/?$ users.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/?$ users.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

And here is the api code with named "users.php".

```
    <?php
// Connect to database
include("../connection.php");
$db = new Database();
$connection = $db->getConnstring();

$request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

switch($request_method) {
    case 'GET':
    // Retrieve Users
    if (!empty($_GET["user_id"])) {
        $id = intval($_GET["user_id"]);
        get_users($user_id);
    } else {
        get_users();
    }
    break;

    case 'POST':
    // Create User
    create_user();
    break;

    default:
    // Invalid Request Method
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
    break;
}

function get_users($user_id=0) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
    if ($user_id != 0) {
        $query .= "Where user_id=" . $user_id . "LIMIT 1";
    }
    $response = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $response[] = $row;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}

function create_user() {
    global $connection;

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $username = $data["username"];
    $email = $data["email"];
    $password = $data["password"];
    $confirm_password = $data["confirmPassword"];
    $status = 0;
    $user_role = 0;

    echo $query = "INSERT INTO user SET username='" . $username . "', email='" . $email . "', password='" . $password . "', confirm_password='" . $confirm_password . "', status='" . $status . "', user_role='" . $user_role . "'";

    if (mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => 'User Registered Successfully.'
        );
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 500,
            'message' => 'User Addition Failedl'
        );
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

How can I solve this problem. Looking to your reply.

Comment: Your echoing the query `echo $query = "INSERT INTO...`, dont do that.

Comment: Also your script is open to sql injection, use prepared queries and dont store passwords in plain text.

Comment: And your sending the `405 Method Not Allowed`, which will be triggered for CORS each time. Maybe you would be better of using a micro framework, which handles this stuff for ya.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right. I used "POST" method. :)
So, do you mean that I have to use a framework for CORS exactly.
Can't I use normal php for this api?

Comment: Please let me know about the solution carefully. :)

Comment: Great. It's solved